# Mostrar unicamente los datos de un ID especifico en Flutter & Realtime Database de Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

tengo una consulta. Estaba siguiendo un tutorial para mostrar en mi perfil de la app, los datos del usuario logeado. En el caso que encontré, me trae todos los datos que se encuentren en el nodo "usuarios" y no según el ID.

Les dejo una captura de un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, tengo en la variable userID el ID del usuario que se logeo. Pero no logro encontrar la manera de mostrar los datos de unicamente este id y no del resto.

```
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  String userEmail = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email;
  String userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance; //Creamos una instancia del FirebaseAuth

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _users_Ref = fb.reference().child("usuarios");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Bienvenido"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Email: $userEmail"),
              Text("Usuario ID: $userID"),

              Flexible(child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                  query: _users_Ref,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot SnapData, Animation<double> animation, int index){
                return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(SnapData.value['nombre']),);
              }))
            ]
          )
        ),

    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.clear_outlined),
      onPressed: () async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.remove('email');
        _signout(context);
      },
    ),);
  }
```

En este caso, me trae el nombre tanto del primero como del segundo ID. Hay alguna forma de filtrar esto? He leído que tal vez es mas fácil firestore que usar realtime database, como tengo ahora?

Este caso especifico es para el perfil del usuario en la app. Como todos sabemos seria para mostrar por ejemplo, su nombre, apellido, etc y que este luego pueda modificar estos datos.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el resultado de un registro en específico conociendo su ID puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
final _users_Ref = fb.reference().child("usuarios/${userID}");
```

donde `userID` es el identificador del registro